# JSP page values are not getting populated after getting values from JSP popup window

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I am passing JSP values to JSF's backing bean. Once I get the values in bean, then I am trying to assign values to inputText fields with setters method, something like this.

```
public void testProcess(){

empBean.setEmpName(empBean.getEmpId());

}
```

testProcess method is called in the action of the JSP page.

My question when I set the value in the bean, my JSF page's values are not getting populated. Do I need to explicitly refresh my JSF page, if so how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to refresh the main page. What happens on the server will not automatically make something happen on the client (browser).

One fairly common pattern for this type of operation is to have the popup do the form post using ajax (easy with many javascript frameworks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)). See http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ for a nice example using the jQuery form plugin. In the response handler for the ajax-call, you reload the main page (using the window.opener property) and close the popup. In the example with the jQuery Form plugin, you would do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {    
        // reload main page
        window.opener.location.reload();
        // close popup
        window.close();
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

The reason you want to submit the form using ajax is that you want to wait to refresh the main page until the post is completed and doing a regular post will cause the popup to reload, which in some browsers will invalidate the window.opener property, making it impossible to reload the main page.

Comment: I do have a javascript method in the onclick method of my jsp page where I am calling testProcees method to pass jsp values to my bean. So if I have `window.opener.location.reload();` in the onclick of button in jsp page, would I be able to reload the JSF page? Another question is onlick method or action method of button would invoke first?

Comment: There is no such thing as an action method on a button. Only onclick. There is an action property on the form tag, but that is what the above code using jQuery form takes care of. It prevents the usual form post behavior and instead post it using ajax.  All you need is a form with a proper action url and a submit button (input type="submit"). Pleas look over the links I included again.